# Replace variable name in loop in R

Tags: r, loops, variables

Is there a way to automate the following in a loop? rather than writing all by hand:

```
hour_1 <- aggregate(hour_1$freq, by=list(country=hour_1$country), FUN=sum)

hour_2 <- aggregate(hour_2$freq, by=list(country=hour_2$country), FUN=sum) 

hour_3 <- aggregate(hour_3$freq, by=list(country=hour_3$country), FUN=sum) 


hour_4 <- aggregate(hour_4$freq, by=list(country=hour_4$country), FUN=sum) 

hour_5 <- aggregate(hour_5$freq, by=list(country=hour_5$country), FUN=sum) 

hour_6 <- aggregate(hour_6$freq, by=list(country=hour_6$country), FUN=sum) 

hour_7 <- aggregate(hour_7$freq, by=list(country=hour_7$country), FUN=sum) 

hour_8 <- aggregate(hour_8$freq, by=list(country=hour_8$country), FUN=sum) 

hour_9 <- aggregate(hour_9$freq, by=list(country=hour_9$country), FUN=sum) 

hour_10 <- aggregate(hour_10$freq, by=list(country=hour_10$country), 
FUN=sum)
```

I want smth like a for loop that takes the number of hours automatically.

Thx :)

Comment: please provide some reproducible code and better explain what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I would consider using the `get()` function.  You could have a for loop iterate over a vector of object names `c('hour_1','hour_2',...,'hour_n')`, and I believe `tmp <- get('hour_1')` and `tmp$freq, tmp$country`, etc will achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Put `hour_1:n` into one big dataset first with the necessary columns. `rbind(hour_1, hour_2, hour_n)`, and add a column for the 'hour'.  Then you can just do `aggregate(freq ~ country + hour, hours, sum)` once on the big set. Keeping separate datasets and using `get()` etc is a nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: I want smth like a million dollars.

Comment: sorry for not being clear in my question, im new to posting in stackoverflow. thank you for your feedback I will try the suggested code and let u know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but the best approach is to use lists and the `lapply` or `sapply` functions instead of loops.

```
hour.in <- mget( paste0('hour_', 1:10) )
hour.out <- lapply( hour.in, function(x) aggregate(x$freq, 
    by=list(country=x$country), FUN=sum) )
names(hour.out) <- paste0('hour_', 1:10)
```

Now all the results are in `hour.out` and can be accessed individually, or further processed using `lapply` or `sapply`.

Comment: I was not aware of `mget()`.  This is very useful!

Comment: Extending this slightly, it might be nice to put it all in one dataset too: `hour.in <- Map(cbind, hour.in, hour=seq_along(hour.in)); hours <- do.call(rbind, L); aggregate(freq ~ country + hour, hours, sum)`

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try your code and let you know.